# Basic commands (db2level) not running on no cost Db2 Community Edition 11.5.5 (latest)

Tags: db2, db2-luw

The previous DB2 Express-C versions were working fine over the years, but the basic commands not running on no cost [Db2 Community Edition 11.5.5 (latest)](https://www.ibm.com/in-en/analytics/db2/trials) .

after installing the Db2 Community Edition 11.5.5, when running the **db2level** command, it gives the error:

```
SQL1022C  There is not enough memory available to process the command.
```

and below links didn't help:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-sql1022c-there-not-enough-memory-available-process-command-after-changing-hostname-db2-server
- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/running-db2level-db2-command-window-returning-sql1022c

Some my findings are:

```
db2set' not working  - DBI1302E  Invalid parameter detected.

'db2set -all' working   - DB2_EXTSECURITY=YES

'db2level' - SQL1022C  There is not enough memory available to process the command.

'db2start' not working - SQL1390C  The environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not defined or is invalid.

DB2 icon not presented on taskbar

db2 get dbm cfg | find "SYSADM"  - not working (no output)

db2 get dbm cfg - DB21018E  A system error occurred. The command line processor could not continue processing.

db2 update dbm cfg using sysadm_group DB2ADMNS - DB21018E  A system error occurred. The command line processor could not continue processing.
```

---

- Followed the same recommended steps (for DB2 installation) as being following since DB2 9.7 version (on WIN 8.1 machine + RAM 8 GB).
- My logged-in user is machine administrator
- The supplied user is 'db2admin'
- Now on the problem machine, OS is Windows 10 Pro + RAM 8 GB.
- 1. Ran the setup.exe after extracting the downloaded zip
- 2. From the DB2 Setup Launchpad > Install a Product > DB2 Version 11.5.5.0 Server Editions > Install Now > then installed with all default settings
- DB2 setup installed successfully but DB2 commands not working as explained above

---

[image: DB2 Commands Output]

Comment: Why did you use the tags `db2-400` and `java`? Provide information on how you installed Db2 and on which OS. The errors hint at an installation problem on your side.

Comment: Do you run all these commands from Start -> Run -> db2cwadmin.bat?

Comment: Yes @Mark Barinstein, all commands are run on **DB2 Command Window - Administrator**

Comment: @data_henrik, I followed the same steps as being following since DB2 9.7 version:

My OS is **Windows 10 Pro**

`1. Ran the setup.exe after extracting the downloaded zip`
`2. From the DB2 Setup Launchpad > Install a Product > DB2 Version 11.5.5.0 Server Editions > Install Now > then installed with all default settings`

Comment: And are you still on the same machine when you installed Db2 9.7...? Please add details to your question by editing that question. What steps did you perform, what type of machine including RAM is it, were you admin or regular user when installing, ...?

Comment: @data_henrik, No, this is new machine. Updated the question with more details.

Comment: Does your current OS user you run db2 commands from belong to the `DB2ADMNS` group? What's the full output of `db2set -all`, `echo %DB2INSTANCE%`, `db2ilist`?

Comment: Yes, I added both users into **DB2ADMNS** group (**1.** My logged-in user 'Kishore' and **2.** DB2 supplied user 'db2admin')...Commands Output added in the question.

Comment: According to the output you provided, there is no db2 instances at all under this Db2 copy. `db2ilist` shows empty output. This is why probably `DB2INSTANCE` env variable and db2 global registry variable DB2INSTDEF are not set. It's strange that `DB2_EXTSECURITY` is set to different values in your text message and in the picture. Anyway, you must create a Db2 instance first with, say, `db2icrt` utility.

Comment: I changed the **DB2_EXTSECURITY** value. 
After setting the values of **DB2INSTANCE**, it's started working as normally.

Thanks @MarkBarinstein

Comment: @MarkBarinstein,

You should post a Answer for what you suggested and it worked for me, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @kishore_2021 Honestly I didn't get what you did after the installation. Did you change this registry variable manually after the installation? Any other manual changes?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, yes the latest DB2 11.5.5 version not setting these environment variables, so need to set, otherwise you can't work like DB2 Express-C

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but after installing db2 with administrator privileges (starting setup.exe as an admin) the issues were gone and everything was set up as expected.